# How to search sharepoint file across document library

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-search

I'm trying to search files in SharePoint with  `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/search(q='text file')` but it searches only in the root site. Is there any way to search across the document library using graph API?

Something similar to `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query`. This endpoint searches files across the document library.

Is it possible to implement the `POST` api call behavior in the `GET` api call? Why because the response from `POST` api call doesn't provide information about file-mimeType, so I need to switch to `GET` api call.

Comment: What if you call search on drive not root? 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/search(q='text file')

Comment: Nope. Even this doesn't work it behaves the same. I have many sites but this doesn't search files from other sites. @user2250152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the fields you want back in the response, as part of the fields sub-property. Specify `mimeType`.

To retrieve a custom property for a `driveItem`, query `listItem` instead.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
```

Request body

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "text file"
                // filter by contentClass
                //"queryString": "text file contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary"
            },
            "fields": [
                "id",
                "fileName",
                "contentClass",
                "createdDateTime",
                "lastModifiedDateTime",
                "webUrl",
                "sharepointIds",
                "createdBy",
                "modifiedBy",
                "parentReference",
                "mimeType",
                "fileType"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Specify select properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-6-specify-select-properties)

Comment: Cool Thanks @user2250152 . This makes sense but `name` is missing in this response can't we pull the name of the file/folder using `listItem`?
And by any chance can we restrict the OneDrive files in this search and search only SharePoint files.

Comment: @WSIAppfactory Updated the answer and added "fileName" field. I'm not sure if you can filter only SharePoint files. Try to add field contentClass and try to filter by contentClass

Comment: The `webUrl` returned from the API call looks like `downloadUrl` & it downloads the specific file/document. Is there any way to fetch the `previewUrl` (URL to open the specific document/file)?