# Graph API returns mimeType of OneNote files FOLDER

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I'm trying to fetch SharePoint files/folders using `POST v1.0/search/query` & I could see `mimeType` of some OneNote files are returned as `Folder`.
Unable to figure out the root cause for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

All notes from OneNote notebook are stored on Microsoft OneDrive in their own specific folder.

I've checked the documentation but I couldn't find any explanation why the `mime-type` for OneNote files on OneDrive is `folder`.

It seems that OneNote file is some kind of a virtual file system.

Resource:

[OneNote](https://www.directive.com/blog/the-end-of-onenote-as-you-know-it-part-2.html)

Comment: I don't think so, I just created a new OneNote file & its `mimeType` is returned in the API response as `Folder`. [API used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69158081/16349236)